# Multiple DropDown list in GridView in C# and Asp.net like city,state,country

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to develop 3 dropdownlists city, state, country. When I select the country then it should only show states which are in selected country same for city & state

ASP.NET CODE:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="manager" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="username" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ma_city" SortExpression="ma_city">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_city" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" SelectedIndex='<%# Eval("city_id") %>' SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ma_city") %>' DataSourceID="city">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ma_city") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ma_state" SortExpression="ma_state">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_state" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged1" SelectedIndex='<%# Bind("state_id") %>' SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ma_state") %>' DataSourceID="state">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ma_state") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ma_country" SortExpression="ma_country">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_country" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="country" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="Id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged" SelectedIndex='<%# Eval("countrt_id") %>' SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ma_country") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ma_country") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ma_pincode" HeaderText="ma_pincode" SortExpression="ma_pincode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ma_phone_no" HeaderText="Ma_phone_no" SortExpression="Ma_phone_no" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and i also use below code in every event like (This is auto generate in visualstudio 2017 ):

```
DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I use two type of code to get gridview reference by:

```
 GridView gridView = (GridView)((((Control)sender).Page.Items[GridView1]));
        GridViewRow gridViewRow = gridView.SelectedRow;
        DropDownList dpl5 = (DropDownList)gridViewRow.FindControl("ddl_state");
        DropDownList dpl6 = (DropDownList)gridViewRow.FindControl("ddl_city");
```

code:-

```
GridViewRow gridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        DropDownList dpl5 = (DropDownList)gridViewRow.FindControl("ddl_state");
        DropDownList dpl6 = (DropDownList)gridViewRow.FindControl("ddl_city");
```

This both give me null as return.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but I would seriously consider naming things properly `DropDownList5` and `dpl5`, what on earth are they? Give them meaningful names: `ddlCountry` and `dplCountry` could be a good start. The same applies to labels. When you review the code later you will be thankful.

Comment: In which event you are trying to get that drop down list ? if its `GridView1_RowEditing` event then try doing this `(gridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex]).FindControl("DropDownList5") as DropDownList`

Comment: It is not clear which dropdown is used for what. And also it is not clear how the code you shared is being executed... What issue you are facing with the code by the way?

Comment: @CoderofCode i try it give gridviewrow `FindControl("dropdownllist5")` return null . i think it  because i use **label** in `ItemTemplate`  and **DropDownlist** in `EditItemTemplate`